# How to edit matlabpool cluster configuration without using GUI

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I am trying to edit the configuration properties of matlabpool on a cluster. I want to edit the ppn/nodes/walltime using a terminal because the GUI I am running is pretty slow. I know how to set the configuration using the cluster profile manager. Is there a way to edit the script which may be generated by the cluster profile manager in matlab so that I do not need to change the options in the GUI?